# NativeSelect wait until I choose an option

Tags: java, if-statement, select, vaadin

I'm using a framework named Vaadin, in it I use a NativeSelect, that works like an HTML select. And I want to setVisible(true) when one option is chosen.

Here is my code :

```
List<String> behaviourData = new ArrayList<>();
behaviourData.add(new String("end"));
behaviourData.add(new String("end-dx6"));
NativeSelect behaviour1 = new NativeSelect("Select", behaviourData);
behaviour1.addValueChangeListener(event -> Notification.show("Value changed:",    String.valueOf(behaviour1.getValue()), Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION));
if (behaviour1.getValue().equals("end-dx6")) {
    System.out.print("else if");
    hop1.setVisible(true);
    out1.setVisible(true);
    nextHop.setVisible(true);
    outGoing.setVisible(true);
 }
```

But when I launch my page, I have an error because behaviour1 is empty, I understand I try to surrender by try/catch but after, when I change the value of the select it doesn't enter into my if condition. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It seems that `if` statement is supposed to be in ValueChangeListener. Otherwise, if will never be executed and will probably fail.

Comment: It doesn't works when I put my if statement into ValueChangeListener

Comment: It works, sorry my fault, I was forgetting an {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing `behaviour1.getValue()` during initialization is pointless because it's null at this time (unless you explicitly call `setValue`).

If you want to run the code when the value is selected you should add this code inside the ValueChangeListener.

Something like this should work:

```
behaviour1.addValueChangeListener(
    new ValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event){
            Notification.show("Value changed:",    String.valueOf(behaviour1.getValue()), Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);
            if (behaviour1.getValue().equals("end-dx6")) {
                System.out.print("else if");
                hop1.setVisible(true);
                out1.setVisible(true);
                nextHop.setVisible(true);
                outGoing.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Other things you should probably do:

- avoid using String constructor for literals: `behaviourData.add("end-dx6");`
- Check for null when checking value it's possible that user will just remove selected text:

  ```
  //before checking the value
  if(behaviour1.getValue()==null) {
      //nothing is selected, just return
      return;
  }
  ```